# Elementary Inequality from a local olympiad test

Tags: inequality

The problem I'm stuck with is the following :

> Let $a$, $b$, $c$, $x$, $y$ and $z$ be real numbers such that
>
> $a+x \ge b+y \ge c+z \ge 0 $ and $ a+ b+c = x+y+z$
>
> Prove that $ay+bx \ge ac+xz$

As easy as it sounds, I didn't achieve any significant progress after several tries.

Any advice, hint would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you know the inequality of Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: Of course, Is is useful here ?

Comment: Have you tried starting with $(a + b + c)(x + y + z) \geq 0$ and seeing where that takes you?

Comment: @Y.Forman Yes but this won't exhibit the terms $ac$ and $xz$, I tried to involve them expanding biproducts $(a+x)(b+y)$ which are also nonnegative but some terms of unknown sign remain

Comment: @OussamaSarih Or variants of that, e.g., $(a + b - z)(x + y - c) \geq 0$? This will exhibit all the terms.

Comment: from where Comes this Problem?

Comment: and from which Country?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
(ay+bx) - (ac+xz) &= a(\color{red}{y-c}) + x(b-z) \\
&= a(\color{red}{a+b - x -z}) + x(b-z)\\
&= a(a-x) + (a+x)(b-z)\\
&= \tfrac12(a-x)^2 + \tfrac12(a^2-x^2) + (a+x)(b-z)\\
&= \tfrac12(a-x)^2 + \tfrac12(a+x)(a-x+2b-2z)\\
&= \tfrac12(a-x)^2 + \tfrac12(a+x)(\color{red}{a+b-x-z}+b-z)\\
&= \tfrac12(a-x)^2 + \tfrac12(a+x)(\color{red}{y-c} + b-z)\\
&= \tfrac12(a-x)^2 + \tfrac12(a+x)(b+y-c-z)\\
&\geqslant 0
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Let us try to minimize
$$\varphi = a y + b x - ac - x z$$

We suppose that $a,b,c,x,y,z$ are given, satisfying the required conditions.

Without any computation one can decrease $\varphi$ by decreasing $b$ and $y$ by the same amount. Indeed, it doesn't change the condition
$a+b+c = x+y+z$ and it decreases $\varphi$ because $a+x\ge 0$. Hence we can suppose that $\boxed{b+y=c+z}$.

With the same argument, one can decrease $\varphi$ by decreasing $a$ and $x$ by the same amount, because $b+y\ge c+z$. We can do this until $\boxed{a+x=b+y}$.

Let $2 m:=a+x = b+y=c+z$. One has $6m = a+b+c+ x+y+z=2 (a+b+c)$
hence $\boxed{a+b+c = 3m}$ and $x + y+ z = 3m$. One has $\boxed{x = 2m-a}$, $\boxed{y = 2m-b}$, $\boxed{z = 2m-c}$

Replacing these values into $\varphi$, leads to
$$\boxed{\varphi = 2 (m-a)^2\ge 0}$$

Indeed,
$$ay+bx=a(2m-b)+b(2m-a)=2m(a+b) - 2ab=2m(3m-c)-2ab$$
and
$$-ac-xz = -ac-(2m-a)(2m-c) = -4m^2+2m(a+c)-2ac$$
hence
$$\varphi=2m^2+2ma-2a(b+c) = 2m^2+2ma-2a(3m-a)=2(m-a)^2$$